# Ionic App iOS Build error with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ionic3

I integrated google analytics plugin in my ionic3 app but on iOS I have build issue…

```
/app/platforms/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.m:19:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h' file not found
 #import "google/protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is my ionic info report:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-sim : 6.1.2 
    Node    : v7.7.0
    npm     : 5.7.1 
    OS      : macOS Sierra
    Xcode   : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I installed also these because I had Firebase Id not found:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (4.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.17)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.9)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.3)
Installing Protobuf (3.5.0)
Installing nanopb (0.3.8)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.
```

Have you an advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by checking the version requirement of the push plugin

My version is 2.2.3
Installation Requirements

> Cordova CLI 7.1 above
>
> Cordova IOS 4.5 above
>
> Cocopod 1.1.1 above

Please see the link and follow the version requirement:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#xcode

And then

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platfrom add ios
cd platforms/ios
pod install
```